# MVC3: Submit string - parse fails on IE and Chrome

Tags: c#, string, asp.net-mvc-3, parsing

I have an issue with the submitted form information. Decimal parsing fails when I try to parse a string returned through Interner Explorer or Chrome but not on Firefox or Safari. The strings looks exactly the same in Visual Studio. I made this debugging bit:

```
var asd3 = collection["formValue"]; // Get it from the FormCollection
var asd4 = asd3.Replace(",", ".");  // Change the punctuation
var asd5 = Decimal.Parse(asd4);     // Make the string into a decimal
var asd6 = Math.Round(asd5, 1);     // Round it
```

It fails on `asd5` when trying to parse the decimal out of `asd4` with the error: `Input string was not in a correct format.`

Here's an image of the strings. Top is Firefox and below Internet Explorer.

[image]

What on earth could be the problem here?

Comment: Always parse numbers using a specific culture info. Example: 'Decimal.Parse(number, new CultureInfo("en-US"))'. If the input is "5.5" in both examples then it will never fail when you specify the culture info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What on earth could be the problem here?

Culture.

In your debugger inspect the value of `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and you will see differences between your browsers.

If you have a different culture set in your browser this culture will be used by ASP.NET when parsing values especially if you haven't explicitly specified the culture in your web.config:

```
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
```

If this is set to `auto` then the browser culture will be used.

Another possibility is to force invariant culture when parsing to ensure that `.` (dot) will be the decimal separator.

```
var asd5 = Decimal.Parse(asd4, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Yes! This solved it, changed the web.config's culture from auto to defined culture. Thank you!